# Cannot edit, delete or copy any file from /sys directory in Android?

Tags: file-system, system

I can't edit, delete or copy any file from `/sys` directory in Android. How can I fix this? I have root access. I made `/sys` readable and writable using Root Explorer and Root Browser but that didn't solve the problem.

When I attempt to edit a text file, I just receive "failed saving `text`".

According to @DeathMaskSalesman, it appears the **/sys** partition is made uneditable at boot. So I suppose I should edit the files while in recovery mode. How can I do that exactly? Or does someone have a better idea?

Comment: The **/sys** partition is made uneditable at boot. I wasn't able to edit most of the files but two.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Thanks for the useful information. Then, what should I do?

Comment: /sys will not load at recovery. Why would you want to edit it anyway? As for the question itself, the only thing I've seen that "edits" /sys stuff is init.d scripts that run at boot time, so you might want to look into that.

Comment: @AndyYan Thanks for the comment. How exactly should I use these `init` scripts?

Comment: I have added additional content as a answer, please check it out. I don't guarantee this to work, but worth a try as long as you back up properly.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing my comment above. This is getting long so I'll just post it as an answer entry.

You will need to enable init.d if your ROM does not support it, for example with this tool: [LINK: Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androguide.universal.init.d)

After that, read up on Linux scripting and write the script doing what you intend to do. Put the script in /system/etc/init.d and set permission to 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to allow execution. Reboot and see if it works.

Check [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2326585) for more info, as well as an example script which you can refer to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked out your XDA thread. I edited my init.d file... Here it is: `#!/system/bin/sh echo 1200000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq` But, after a reboot, it doesn't edit the text file. Do you know the why?

Comment: I'm currently running a stock ROM, but I already had a init.d file

Comment: If you're just trying to modify the top freq of a CPU (within the kernel limit), apps like Kernel Adiutor will do the job properly.

Comment: This was just 1 simple example. Unfortunately, I can't modify anything...

Comment: Can you provide help?

Comment: Unfortunately not further. I've been using the same method to modify button light behavior on some devices and it had always worked for me.